# Sum values in foreach loop in [php]

Tags: php, laravel

I want to sum `tot_Price` and `unit_Price` respectively so that I can analyze the average of these two attributes.

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ $X_land->house_Type }}</td>
    <td class="address">{{ $X_land->the_Location }}</td>
    <td>{{ $X_land->tot_Price }}</td>
    <td>{{ $X_land->tran_Area }}</td>
    <td>{{ $X_land->unit_Price }}</td>
    <td><button id="opener<?php echo $opencount?>">詳細資訊</button></td>
</tr>
```

How should I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: just use a temporary total container, just `+=` those values

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could add `sum` variable for both `tot_Price` and `unit_Price` and add in foreach loop

```
<?php $sum_tot_Price = 0 ?>
<?php $sum_unit_Price = 0 ?>
@foreach ($yourData as X_land)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $X_land->house_Type }}</td>
    <td class="address">{{ $X_land->the_Location }}</td>
    <td>{{ $X_land->tot_Price }}</td>
    <td>{{ $X_land->tran_Area }}</td>
    <td>{{ $X_land->unit_Price }}</td>
    <td><button id="opener<?php echo $opencount?>">詳細資訊</button></td>
</tr>
<?php $sum_tot_Price += $X_land->tot_Price ?>
<?php $sum_unit_Price += $X_land->unit_Price ?>
@endforeach

<tr>
    <td>Sum tot_Price {{ $sum_tot_Price}}</td>
    <td>Sum unit_Price {{ $sum_unit_Price}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Works!!
Thank for your tutorial.

Answer (score 5):

**Assume:**

```
@foreach($lands as $X_land)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $X_land->house_Type }}</td>
    <td class="address">{{ $X_land->the_Location }}</td>
    <td>{{ $X_land->tot_Price }}</td>
    <td>{{ $X_land->tran_Area }}</td>
    <td>{{ $X_land->unit_Price }}</td>
    <td><button id="opener<?php echo $opencount?>">詳細資訊</button></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

**You can get total like this:**

```
{{$lands->sum('tot_Price')}}
{{$lands->sum('unit_Price')}}
```

**Or you can get average:**

```
{{$lands->avg('tot_Price')}}
{{$lands->avg('unit_Price')}}
```

Comment: Hi, I had add pagination method into my project. I run into a problem that `{{$lands->sum('tot_Price')}}` will only sum the current page's  `tot_Price`, how should I do to calculate  `tot_Price` of all pages but not just one page?  Is there any solution to create some code in controller? Thanks for helping me with this.

Answer (score 1):

**To be very simple,**

You need to focus on the `@foreach` loop first,
e.g `@foreach($people as $person)` 
and there is the `salary` which you can access in `foreach`,
Through `$person->salary`

If you want to calculate the sum of salaries then use a simple sum like this, 
`$people->sum('salary')`, Remember not use `$person`

**In your case** 
`{{$lands->sum('tot_Price')}}` 
`{{$lands->sum('unit_Price')}}`